# Why is this inset distorting so badly?

Tags: modeling, distort

I am attempting to inset a group of faces however they are distorting very badly, they even inset individually fine. All transforms applied, no doubles, face orientation is fine.[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sure https://blend-exchange.com/b/qwQRGZqd

Comment: the topology is bad, it will make the faces overlap if you try to inset, plus there are some other problems, I'm not sure what's the huge extrusion you show though